# ADO connection using VBA unable to retreive all records in sharepoint list

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ado

Title says it all. I have connected to the sharepoint list using the ADO connection in VBA. I have set the cursorlocation of the recordset as adUseClient already and got the entire recordCount right but the problem is I only can access the first and last records for some reason. I am trying to display all records directly to a listbox.

My BOF is always false even after many getRows and my EOF becomes true right after the first getRows. Only movePrevious can be done but BOF, EOF is still always False, True respectively.

One more odd thing is that if I import all of the records to a worksheet, all records were there.

Edit: here is my code

```
Dim connection As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim query As String
Dim i As Variant           'holds the getrows       
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; WSS; IMEX=4; RetrievedIds=Yes; DATABASE= <sharepoint link>;LIST={GUID};"

query = "Select * From [Table];"

rs.CursorLocation = 3
rs.Open query, connection
rs.MoveFirst

MsgBox rs.BOF
MsgBox rs.EOF
i = rs.GetRows
MsgBox rs.BOF
MsgBox rs.EOF
rs.MovePrevious
i = rs.GetRows
MsgBox rs.BOF
MsgBox rs.EOF
rs.MovePrevious

Form.Listbox.List = i
```

Comment: Without showing your code, it's hard to tell anything. I would guess that while getting the `recordCount`, you moved already to the end of your data.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case. Just as said when I directly import the data into a worksheet, all data is present. If I use getrows, the only data that I would get is the first and last ones. I view it using the listbox.

I'll add my code for clarifications.

Comment: @FunThomas added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to read data from the recordset, the code is really simple. You don't need to take care about `CursorLocation` and you don't need to execute any move operations. The command `GetRows` reads *all* fields from *all* records into a 2-dimensional array. No need to check `BOF` or `EOF` - except if you need to catch the case that the query returns no data at all (in that case, `BOF` and `EOF` both are `True`).

Also no need to create the recordset in advance, the `connection.Execute` method creates and returns a recordset (of course, your way works also).

One thing about the 2-dimensional array that is returned by `GetRows`: The first index is the *field* index, the second the *row* index. The ListBox.List expects it vice versa, so you have to use `Transpose` when you assign the data:

```
Dim connection as Object, rs as Object
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connection.Open "<your connection string>"
Dim query As String
query = "Select * From [Table];"
Set rs = conn.Execute(query)

If rs.EOF or rs.EOF Then
    ... no data found...
Else
    Dim data
    data = rs.GetRows
    Form.Listbox.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(data)
End If
```

*Remark*: I have no Sharepoint Table available at the moment, but have already worked with it and the behaviour was not different from other data sources, so I expect this code will work for you. Tested it with a query agains an Excel Sheet.

*Another Remark:* I always advocate to use early binding. Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiceX Data Objects" (Tools->References) and change the first line to

```
Dim connection as ADODB.Connection, rs as ADODB.RecordSet
Set connection = New ADODB.Connection
```

**Update**
The `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` throws an type mismatch if some of your fields are empty (NULL). Use a small replacement routine instead:

```
Function myTranspose(a As Variant) As Variant
    ReDim b(LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2), LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1))
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
            b(j, i) = a(i, j)
        Next
    Next
    myTranspose = b
End Function
```

For the early vs late binding: Noone needs to enable the reference manually, the VBA project "knows" that it is needed and keep that information when running on a different computer. You have to do this only if you use a reference that is installed on a different path (as it may be the case for some AddOns), but all the standard office and windows references are found automatically.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'll sure try this code. I can't use early binding because I need to share files with other people. Need to do late binding in that matter.

Comment: Even if you share it if with other people: "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8" should be available on every Windows computer and Office version. If not, late binding will also not work.

Comment: It's tedious for them to enable those references so I just used late bind

Comment: Form.Listbox.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(data) throws a type mismatch. Error is now different but still there is an error.

Comment: Never knew that is the case about early bind vs late bind. Thanks for the information! 

For the updated code, I am unsure if I will continue the idea. I think I am better of with copying the recordset to a worksheet. I also needed the headers but I am uncertain of how to get it from the sharepoint list.

I will still try the code for your continuous effort on helping me. Thank you. You are the only one who tried to help.

Comment: To copy data to a sheet, you can use the (Range)-method `CopyFromRecordset(rs)`. To get the field names, loop over the `Fields`-collection of the recordset and use the `Name`-property. As `Fields` is the default property of a record set, you can simply write `rs(0).name` to get the name of the first field.

Comment: I see that is how you get the fields. There seems to be a problem if I copied the data to the worksheet. It seems to be that there is an error on saving the changes if there are multiple users of the file at the very same time. I have read multiple discussions about this, and think that it is still not resolved. Might do the connection of the listbox and sharepoint list directly in order to avoid the editing of the file.

Comment: The function worked! Need to check with my team if there will still be an error. For now, I still need to add the field names into it. Do you have a solution to that as well?

Comment: I have manually input the fields on a separate listbox on top of the listbox containing the data from sharepoint list. Now the problem is the side scrolling of the listbox. I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: I think I have a solution to my problem. I think that it is not appropriate to directly put the data from a sharepoint list to the listbox if you have other functionalities other than for display purposes. Doing some search function tends to make it very difficult because of null values. It might be possible but I am unaware of how to work around that. Only with your help do I have the chance to even make the direct connection work.

Comment: For the saving error in SharePoint, I think that it is better to let the other people download the file instead of co-authoring it. It is meant to get the data only and the data can be retrieved from the list. It is an app of some sort. Thanks again for the help! Would not have explored much about ADO connection to a sharepoint list without it.